Frontend (public) pages showing Page not found
I have not been able to get public pages to work correctly. So far I've tried events and profiles. When attempting to load those pages, I get Page not found.
I am able to set-up a WP page and include the corresponding shortcode for the event and profile.. and this works. My host advises this is the workaround for a few others experiencing the same problem, but I'd rather not create a static page for each event, contribution page, profile, etc. Also, I am not sure tokens passed in the URL will work.
So far I have checked a lot of settings, but the items below have been checked specifically based on responses from others with this issue:

Confirmed Permalink structure is set to Post Name
Confirmed Wordpress base page is selected and page exists (civicrm)
Confirmed same page is set in Settings - WordPress Integration (System Settings - CMS Database Integration)
Cleared caches (in CiviCRM settings located in WP)

Thank you for any assistance!
CiviCRM 5.72.1
Wordpress 6.5.3
PHP 8.1.28

Are you using Wordfence?

no... I've also disabled the couple of plugins I do have running to confirm if they were causing the issue.

Does link from Civi work?

I am not sure what you are referring to: link from Civi? For example, if I am in the event configuration (online registration is enabled), and I go to Event Links - the three public links do not work because it links to public page at /event/info/?reset=1&id=13. The result is Page not found.

Great suggestions, but I finally figured it out.
My actual base page was the problem. When I created a new page and assigned it, the problem went away. I had tested this yesterday, but hadn't cleared the caches so I didn't see the fix until making the change and clearing the caches today.
At first, I thought it might be the name of the page, but I deleted the original page that was created by the install and created a new page with the same name - and that still works. So something about the original page must have been the problem.
Thanks for all the suggestions! It helps to keep me at it!

Glad to hear it!  https://chat.civicrm.org is also a great place to get help from the community.  Depending on the issue, someone may ask you to post the question here on SE in conjunction with a chat question, since this is more helpful for others with the same issue.

When receiving "page not found" errors in WordPress for CiviCRM, I've found these are the usual culprits:

WordPress ships with a .htaccess file in the webroot.  If this is missing, CiviCRM URLs to public pages will fail.
Sometimes the WP permalink cache gets borked.  You can go to WP's Settings >> Permalinks and click Save without making changes to fix it.

